# join 2 tables from 3 depending on null ID

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have 3 tables :

```
CREATE TABLE B (
  id         INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  personName VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE TABLE C (
  id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  companyName VARCHAR2(200)
);

CREATE TABLE A (
  id   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  id_b INTEGER REFERENCES B(id),
  id_c INTEGER REFERENCES C(id),
  CHECK ( id_b IS NULL OR id_c IS NULL )
);
```

But table A point to only one table at a time : if idB has value then idC is null.

I am trying now to do a single query where I select all rows and for each row : either it is a person row ( id, id_B, personName) or it is a company row(id, id_B, companyName).

Is there any way to do this without using stored procedures ?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. As formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  a.id,
  coalesce(b.id, c.id),
  coalesce(b.person_name, c.company_name)
from
  A a,
  B b,
  C c
where
  a.id_b = b.id (+) and
  a.id_c = c.id (+)
```

P.S. Maybe you should consider to change your check constraint like `nvl2(id_b, 1, 0) + nvl2(id_c, 1, 0) = 1`

Comment: Why the legacy oracle comma joins and not the ANSI standard joins?

Comment: They are shorter, easier to read and works without errors while ANSI joins on occasion reported as 'yet another implementation bug had been found'.

Comment: They are not easier to read - the join conditions are mixed in with the filter conditions and are not always obvious, you cannot do `FULL OUTER JOIN`s and it is easy to get the `(+)` on the wrong side. ANSI joins are much easier to read.

Comment: It's hard to objectively dispute about readability. I'd say well-written old-style statement is easier than well-written ANSI-style statement while bad-written are both hard. But bugreports about ansi joins are easy-to-touch fact of our world, so I prefer use them only if nessessary. It's very sad to spend 10 hours of Saturday to debug mystical error and then read Metalink note about 'That's just join error. We are sorry'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select id,id_b,personName from A join B on A.id_b = B.id
union all
select id,id_c,companyName from A join C on A.id_c = C.id
```